# Insert data to MySQL using WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to insert data into a database, but it's not working, and I don't know if it's the insert code or the Post method that is wrong. The intended functionality is that when I press the button it triggers the function which inserts the data into the database, for example `UserID=123,CourseID=1;`

This is the database:

[image]

This is my code:

```php
<?php
global $wpdb;
if(isset($_POST['attendance-btn'])) {
    $wpdb->insert(
        Attendance_Table,
        array(
            'User_ID'=>$UserID,
            'Course_ID'=>$Course_ID),
        array( '%d','%d' )
     );
?>        

<form action="zoom-meetings.php" method="post">
    <button  name="attendance-btn" class="Attendence-btn" type="submit" >
        <!-- Join meeting Button -->
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($meeting->ID); ?>" class="tutor-btn bordered-btn"><?php _e('Continue to Meeting', 'tutor-pro'); ?></a>
    </button>  
</form>
```

Comment: Where do you set $UserID variable?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the table name as a string like this:

```
$wpdb->insert(
              'Attendance_Table',
               array(
                            'User_ID'=>$UserID,
                            'Course_ID'=>$Course_ID),
                    array( '%d','%d' )
 );
```

Check these:

1. Is column Attendance_ID index equal to 'Primary'?
2. Does column Current_Date_Time have a default value?
3. Run this code `var_dump($wpdb->last_query)` and run the query in PHPMyAdmin and check the result

Comment: The attendance is primary. The Current_Date_Time is default value set to current time stamp so that it record when the student get the attendance. The code still not working

Comment: run this code and send the result:
```var_dump($wpdb->last_query);var_dump($wpdb->last_error);```